# Error "[Error] expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]" in recursive call

Tags: c++

In the following code, in all the lines where I call the function recursively, I get this error:

> [Error] expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]

I thought it had something to do with me not placing in the variable type,
but when I did that I instead got another error claiming it expects a ',' or '...' in front of '+' or '-'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int lastmove = 0;

// Returns true if you can reach the bottom-right (otherwise returns false).
// You can move up, down, left, or right.  You cannot move diagonally.
// 1 represents a wall.  You cannot go through a wall.
bool winnable(int maze[5][5], int m, int n) {

    //  Testing moves in right, down, left and up directions
    // If the previous move is the opposite vertically or horizontally
    // It is not valid
    if (n<6&& maze[m][++n]!=1 && lastmove!=3){

        if(m==5&&n==5)
            return true;

        lastmove = 1;
        bool winnable(maze,  m,  ++n);
```

Comment: Lose the `bool` here: `bool winnable(maze,  m,  ++n);` or better assign the return value to something.  And post all the code.

Answer (score 0):

To properly call `winnable()` (or any function for that matter), you should not specify its return type.

Instead of attempting this:

```
bool winnable(maze,  m,  ++n);
```

You should call it this way:

```
bool result = winnable(maze,  m,  ++n); // store the result of winnable() for later use
```